# iPhone App - Issue with RSS feed and loadHTMLString:baseURL:

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, rss

I'm parsing an RSS feed (which comes in as an XML) and loading it into a UIWebView - and that works perfectly well.
The problem is with the occasional `<img>` tags that are in the XML - the images they call aren't showing up (although I do get a placeholder bounding-box where they should be appearing.)
The issue is that those `<img>` tags unfortunately contain only *partial* paths, with no domain name - for example:

```
<img src="/news-media/images/football/6.jpg" />
```

To fix that I tried specifying the default domain name in the `baseURL` argument:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://www.myDomain.com"];
[theWebView loadHTMLString:tempHtmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

This does not work - the HTML is still loading fine, but the images are not showing up. This does however eliminate the "broken image" icons I was getting before on the images (the kind you usually get when a web-page is trying to load an image that's missing.) Also, I sometimes get a "received memory warning" message - but not always. Seems to happen when loading a page that contains multiple photos. But even when a page has only one photo and I do not receive the "memory" warning, the photo itself doesn't get loaded.

Any ideas what to do? Am I gonna have to manually append the base-URL to all occurrences of the `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your base URL as a file URL (i.e. a URL to a local file on the device). You want the URL To reference the remote server. Try this:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myDomain.com"];
[theWebView loadHTMLString:tempHtmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: That works - and I marked it as the right answer, so thank you.  I did also find a workaround/hack though, which was to simply use `[tempHtmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"src=" withString:@"src=http://www.myDomain.com"]` to automatically append the domain name to any <img> tag present - and that also worked. Your answer however is definitely the right one as it addresses the issue specifically. So, thanks again!